# How to use CAN correctly for Embedded Communication with extended identifier?

Tags: can-bus

For a project i will have to design a CAN protocol for communicating between devices.

The network consists of a leading system that will have multiple subsystems on the bus. Now this leading system will send commands to the subsystems and the subsystems will periodically send data to the leading system.

Requirements:

- Atleast 160 subsytems
- Able to start multiple subsystems simultaneously

Now i designed this protocol using the extended identifier:

3 bits: Used for priority (8 options)
8 bits: Used for a Node ID (256 systems on the bus)
10 bits: Used for a Message Type ID (1024 messages)
8 bits: Used to Mask the Message Type ID (to reach 256 systems)

So the first 3 bits will be to prioritize messages. For one of the subsystems has a critical error, the leading system will put 0 on this 3 bits, the subsystems know this will be a emergency shutdown signal

The next 8 bits will be used to tell the other systems who the message is from, the leading system will always be value 0. When a subsystems starts and does not have an ID yet, it will have value 255 with a generated id in the data field. The leading system will return the message with the assigned id and generated id in the data field. The subsystem now has an Node ID assigned.

The next 10 bits are used for message types so the receiving system knows what data to expect.
The last 8 bits are used to mask the message type.

For example i want to send a message with id = 8, to subsystem with NodeID 4. The last 18 bits will be:
...[0000001000][00000100]

High priority shutdown:
[000][00000000][1111111111][11111111]
(I'm not sure what to do with the last 18 bits since the first 3 bits will already tell the subsystems to shutdown)

Since i have to start subsystems at the same time, i will make it possible to group subsystems, each subsystem knows who its leading unit is in the group and will also listen to the mask of the leading subsystem. For example:

subsystem 1, 2 and 3 are grouped. Each system knows subsystem 1 is its group leader. So when a message is received with mask of value 1, system 2 and 3 know, they also have to listen. Based on the Message Type ID they will know if they actually have to do something. For starting the subsystems the message type can either be START or GROUP_START. When the message type is GROUP_START, subsystems 2 and 3 know they have to start too.

So normal start on subsystem 1:
[011][00000000][0000000010][00000001]
[Priority 3][from leading system][Message Type ID 2][Subsytem 1]

group_start for group leader 1:
[011][00000000][0000000011][00000001]
[Priority 3][from leading system][Message Type ID 3][Subsystem 1]

New device that needs an ID:
[111][11111111][1111111111][00000000] + data: UUID (6 bytes) & empty (2 bytes)
[Priority 8][from new device][Message Type ID 8][To leading system]

Return message from leading system:
[111][00000000][11111111][11111111] + data: UUID (6 bytes) & New Node ID (2 bytes)

I can't really find good information about how to use this identifier in CAN, so i am not sure if this is a proper implementation.

Comment: "I can't really find good information about how to use this identifier in CAN" What do you mean? This is something you've cooked up yourself, CAN only cares as far as low CAN identifier = high priority.